# Finish some animations from UIViewPropertyAnimator earlier

Tags: ios, swift, animation, duration, uiviewpropertyanimator

I search for a way to add some animations to an `UIViewPropertyAnimator` which finishing earlier then others.
`UIViewPropertyAnimator` have for example a method where you can add animations with a delay

`animator.addAnimations(animation: (()-> Void), delayFactor: CGFloat)`

so the animation starts at 50% of the duration at a `delayFactor` of `0.5`.

I search for something like

`animator.addAnimations(animation: (()->Void), realtiveDuration: CGFloat)`

so the animation ends after 50% of the duration at a `relativeDuration`of `0.5`.

After some research I found a solution by using

```
animator.addAnimations {
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.3) {
            view.alpha = 0.0
        }
    })
}
```

to archive this behavior.
Problem is, I want to use that in some kind of an automatism where I iterate through some elements and call a Method for each of the elements:

```
func animation(view: UIView) -> (() -> Void) {
    return {
        view.alpha = 0.0
    }
}
```

which works fine when using for example the method

`animator.addAnimations(animation: element.animation(element.view), delayFactor: 0.5)`
but I cannot call this inside the

```
.addKeyframe(...){
    element.animation(element.view)
}
```

Maybe some of you guy's have a solution?
I thinking about overriding `UIViewPropertyAnimator` for example to add the asked method `animator.addAnimations(animation: (()->Void), realtiveDuration: CGFloat)` or something, but leaving my comfortzone there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may call like this:

```
  UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: element.animation(element.view))
```